# Limiting web logins to a single machine

Tags: javascript, security

For a password protected site, is there a way to allow users to log in to the site multiple times as long as it's on the same computer (even in different browsers)?

One way I have thought to do it is always send MAC address on login, but that's not available in browsers.  Is there some other way of doing this?

Comment: I would suggest you re-think your approach.  Restricting access per-machine is not widely considered a good method.  You would be better served to have per-user credentials (ie username and password), and supplement with things like a fingerprint scanner or crypto card if you need better security.  Doing it by MAC address will tend to be fragile, and MAC addresses can be faked.

Comment: Yes, I understand what you're saying.  I think that it's just a business decision about how much it's worth spending and how much hassle clients will live with.  Hoping to find a silver bullet that's easier / less expensive.

Answer (score 1):

As I understand it, you want to keep your users logged in to your application even if they close the browser and switch to another one. Briefly looking into this, a possible solution might be to use "flash cookies" or [local shared objects](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Local_Shared_Object), which are managed browser independent. However, there are some security, privacy and legal concerns plus the drawbacks from using the proprietary Flash technology. I would go with Alex's advice of rethinking your approach.

Answer (score 0):

Use a flash (or java, or ...) applet to get the needed unique information.

Comment: Flash can acess any file (http://www.flashmagazine.com/news/detail/flash_player_10_new_feature_load_and_save_files_using_filereference/) : finding an unique information should not be too difficult (registery ?). And it can set browser-shared LSO cookie.